# Keras custom loss function for multivariate normal distribution output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, normal-distribution, loss-function

I have a network which outputs 4 values representing 2 normal distribution parameters as such :

```
[mu1, sigma1, mu2, sigma2]
```

And I would like to train it with a log probability loss function, but I have no clue how to implement the custom loss function.

I tried the following definition but it obviously does not work. All the custom functions I saw use the input values "as such" (as in yPred and yTrue representing the same kind of data) and did not need to split those inputs into different parts for the loss computation.

```
def loss_multivariate_normal(yTrue,yPred):
    p1 = -keras.backend.square(yTrue[0][:]-yPred[0][:])/(2*yPred[1][:])
    p2 = -keras.backend.log(keras.backend.sqrt(2*math.pi*keras.backend.square(yPred[1][:])))
    p3 = -keras.backend.square(yTrue[2][:]-yPred[3][:])/(2*yPred[3][:])
    p4 = -keras.backend.log(keras.backend.sqrt(2*math.pi*keras.backend.square(yPred[3][:])))
    return p1+p2+p3+p4
```

When I fit the function, I get this error

```
InvalidArgumentError: slice index 2 of dimension 0 out of bounds. [[Node: loss/main_output_loss/strided_slice_4 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_main_output_target_0_1, loss/main_output_loss/strided_slice_2/stack_1, loss/main_output_loss/strided_slice_5/stack, loss/main_output_loss/strided_slice_1/stack_1)]]
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I added the error I'm getting. I assumed that the definition of the function would be obviously wrong for someone who've work on similar problems.

Comment: what if you try removing the "[:]" from yTrue and yPred

Comment: I think I found the solution but I need to test it (it gives me no error and seems to run normally but I need to check if my network learns correctly). Instead of treating the inputs as arrays, I use tensorflow's slice to get the column I need : mu1_true = tf.slice(yTrue, [0, 0], [-1, 1]) for example